# mysql_real_escape_string is being ignored

Tags: php, mysql

I would really appreciate any help I can get with this.

I am having real trouble with a form and I cant seem to get mysql_real_escape_string to work at all.

I am using MySQL 5.5 with PHP and to test it out I have created a simple form
Magic Quotes is not turned on at all.

Using this form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="event_ad" action="test.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Event Name:</td>
        <td><input name="event_name" type="text" size="90" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Start Date:</td>
        <td><input name="start_date" type="text" size="90" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Add New Event" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the data is input nto the table using test.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("databasename") or die(mysql_error());

    $name = $_POST['event_name'];
    $sdate = $_POST['start_date'];
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblevents (event_name, event_date) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $sdate . "')";

    mysql_query($sql);

    echo "success";
?>
```

(connection details changed)

When I input the Event Name O'Rielly "Smith" it is inserted into the MySQL table as O'Rielly "Smith"

There is no back slashes, no escaping at all.

I really have scoured the internet trying to work this out but it seems that it works for everyone else.

Am I missunderstanding something fundamental here?
I would thoroughly appreciate if someone could steer me in the right direction.

This is my first post on this forum, and the html and code formating dont seem to be the same as most forums I have visited, and you cant preview so I hope this turns out OK.

Thanx in advance to any who offer help.
Cheers Al.

Comment: Forget mysql_real_escape_string. Use mysqli or PDO and bound arguments instead.

Comment: How do you know that is what it is doing?  Are you echoing `$name`?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't answer your question, but I highly recommend switching to something along the lines of PDO. Mysql functions are being deprecated starting with PHP version 5.4.

Comment: Also If I use the following as an Event Name: <script>blah blah \n ""</script> it gets inserted straight into the table and I can see it exactly as that using phpMyAdmin to look at the table.
I thought that was the sort of thing that mysql_real_escape_string was supposed to stop, by adding back slashes to it.

Comment: Please learn first what escaping is. It's best you know about what you use for what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I input the Event Name O'Rielly "Smith" it is inserted into the MySQL table as O'Rielly "Smith"

That is what is supposed to happen.

Escaping makes the data pass through the query so that the original data ends up in the database. The purpose is not to add extra characters to your stored data, it is to stop characters with special meaning from breaking your SQL.

Answer (score 3):

This is by-design, you shouldn't see any escaped input in your table. It's just for inserting. By using `mysql_real_escape_string`, your query looks like

```
INSERT INTO tblevents (event_name, event_date) VALUES ('O\'Rielly \"Smith\"','1.4.2001')";
```

where these backslashes make sure you don't break the apostrophe

MySQL "deletes" all the backslashes until they're escaped by backslash :)

Comment: +1.  The escaped data is for the query parser only.  The whole point is to get real data into the table.

Comment: Thanx Martin. That is exactly the information I had been looking for, but funnily enough, I couldn't find that anywhere.
I now have a much better understanding of how this works.
Cheers.

Comment: If you like my answer the best, please accept it by ticking it on the left. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think of escaping as the equivalent of wrapping paper on a birthday present.

You escape data so that any special characters in the data lose their special meaning during the transfer process. Once they're "inside" the target system (html page, database record, etc...), the escaping is no longer necessary, as the place where they could have affected the process is now over.

Same with the wrapped present - once the present is received, you don't need the wrapping paper anymore, so it's removed.

Answer (score 0):

It has worked fine.

Removing the `mysql_real_escape_string` will prevent the data being inserted.

Comment: I am begining to understand now, but unfortunately, If I remove the mysql_real_escape_string the data still gets inserted into the table, no matter how out there the data is. This is why I am getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_POST['event_name'];
$sdate = $_POST['start_date'];


$db = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "databasename");

$query = "INSERT INTO tblevents (event_name, event_date) VALUES (?, ?)";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param("ss", $name, $sdate);

$statement->execute();
$statement->close();

$db->close();
```

(I've left out error-checking for connecting)